# Single quote and backquote in regex

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, posix, abap

I'm trying to match a single quote in a string, if it exists I want to display this using `WRITE`.

```
    data text type string value `this is a string containing a ' single quote`.
    find regex `(\'|%27)` in text.
    if sy-subrc = 0.
      write 'found'.
    endif.
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't understand the behaviour of the backquote character in ABAP regex's. And cannot find a resource online with an explanation of how it works. The results I'm getting using it are quite odd, depending on the TEXT string above the match either works or fails.

In PERL you can do things like search for a string variable within a string, eg/:

```perl
    my $tofind = "'"; //a single quote
    my $text = "this is a string containing a ' single quote";
    if($text=~m/$tofind/){
      print "found";
    }
```

Can this method be used in ABAP, or could someone explain how to use backquotes in ABAP?

Comment: What happens if you take the `\\` out of your regex?  I got more consistent results that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the backquote in this case, however what I think you are looking for is the escape character to show that the ' is part of the string/regex

```
data text type string value `this is a string containing a '' single quote`.
    find regex `(''|%27)` in text.
    if sy-subrc = 0.
    write 'found'.
    endif.
```

Note the extra ' in both the defined string as well as the regex.

Edit:  In response to your comment regarding the documentation, if you do an F1 (Help) with your cursor positioned on the word regex, you should be able to access the SAP help for regular expressions.  It did look like most of the syntax were documented there.  (Alternatevily, just press F1 and search for regex).

Answer (score 2):

as a side note, there are easier ways to find a single character.

```
SEARCH text FOR ''''.
if sy-subrc eq 0.
  WRITE: 'Position:' , SY-FDPOS.
endif.
```

Answer (score 0):

In ABAP, [backquotes](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenuntyped_character_literals.htm) are not specific to regular expressions, they are used to define character literals typed [`string`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbuiltin_types_character.htm) (opposed to type "C").

Your only ABAP example code works fine.

Unfortunately, your question is unclear as you don't provide an example of what is not working correctly, so it's impossible to answer precisely.

For information, about the regular expression of your code:

- [`\` (backslash)](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenregex_syntax_signs.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SYNTAX_SIGNS_1) is a kind of "unescape" character: it's to be used when you want to search a character that has normally a special meaning, like those characters: `.()|{}[]` (etc.) As the single quote `'` is not a special character, you don't need to indicate `\`
- `%` (percentage sign) has no special meaning in ABAP regular expressions, nor in text literals. I guess you used `%27` to correspond to the Unicode code point [U+0027](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm) of the single quote (AKA apostrophe), but instead it's interpreted literally by ABAP so it will only correspond to the sequence of the three individual characters.